# React hooks/Jest/Enzyme Test useEffect, which adds and removes event listeners on ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have the following component:

```
export const DeviceModule = (props: Props) => {
  const [isTooltipVisible, changeTooltipVisibility] = useState(false)
  const deviceRef = useRef(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (deviceRef && deviceRef.current) {
      deviceRef.current.addEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, () => changeTooltipVisibility(true))
      deviceRef.current.addEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, () => changeTooltipVisibility(false))
    }
    return () => {
      deviceRef.current.removeEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, () => changeTooltipVisibility(true))
      deviceRef.current.removeEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, () => changeTooltipVisibility(false))
    }
  })

  return (
    // some jsx. When you hover on a div, it triggers one of the event listeners and changes the state. 
  )
}
```

How should I test it using Jest and Enzyme?

**UPDATE 2021. Do not use enzyme!**

The whole story is explained thoroughly [here](https://www.piotrstaniow.pl/goodbye-enzyme).
In short:

1. AirBNB(they created it) stopped supporting it and instead gave it to someone else and right now only one person is taking care of it.
2. It has not been updated for 2 years, which means it does not support react 17(react 18 is right around the corner by the way). There are 3rd party adapters for react 17, but each of them has its issues and it faces the same problem of depending on a project, which has no guarantee of being supported.
3. Functional components(like the one in the question) are hard to make, because enzyme was not intended for them.
4. Enzyme uses some internal react features, which is discouraged and could create even worse problems if react changes.
5. Jest has moved a couple of version up, using different environment, which further complicates things.

The industry standard right now is [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library) It is also recommended  by the react team, who stopped using enzyme as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `jest.mock()` and `jest.requireActual()` to partial mock `react` module. It means you only need to mock `useRef` hook, keep others as original.
2. Use `mocked` helper function of `ts-jest/utils` to make your TS types correctly.
3. Use `Object.defineProperty()` to define the setter and getter methods of `deviceRef`. We will add the spy to the `addEventListener` method of the current element in the setter.
4. Use `jest.resetAllMocks()` to reset partial mocked `react` module to original version after testing.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Props {}

export enum EVENT_TYPE {
  MOUSEOVER = 'MOUSEOVER',
  MOUSEOUT = 'MOUSEOUT',
}

export const DeviceModule = (props: Props) => {
  const [isTooltipVisible, changeTooltipVisibility] = useState(false);
  const deviceRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (deviceRef && deviceRef.current) {
      deviceRef.current.addEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, () => changeTooltipVisibility(true));
      deviceRef.current.addEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, () => changeTooltipVisibility(false));
    }
    return () => {
      if (deviceRef && deviceRef.current) {
        deviceRef.current.removeEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, () => changeTooltipVisibility(true));
        deviceRef.current.removeEventListener(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, () => changeTooltipVisibility(false));
      }
    };
  });

  return <div ref={deviceRef}>my device module</div>;
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { DeviceModule, EVENT_TYPE } from './';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('react', () => {
  const originReact = jest.requireActual('react');
  return {
    ...originReact,
    useRef: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const mUseRef = mocked(useRef);

describe('66561050', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should add event listener for device ref and do cleanup work when component unmount', () => {
    const mRef = { current: {} };
    let addEventListenerSpy!: jest.SpyInstance;
    let removeEventListenerSpy!: jest.SpyInstance;
    Object.defineProperty(mRef, 'current', {
      get() {
        return this._current;
      },
      set(current) {
        if (current) {
          addEventListenerSpy = jest.spyOn(current, 'addEventListener');
          removeEventListenerSpy = jest.spyOn(current, 'removeEventListener');
        }

        this._current = current;
      },
    });
    mUseRef.mockReturnValueOnce(mRef);
    const wrapper = mount(<DeviceModule />);
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, expect.any(Function));
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, expect.any(Function));
    wrapper.unmount();
    expect(removeEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOVER, expect.any(Function));
    expect(removeEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith(EVENT_TYPE.MOUSEOUT, expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66561050/index.test.tsx
  66561050
    ✓ should add event listener for device ref and do cleanup work when component unmount (26 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   80.95 |       80 |      50 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |   80.95 |       80 |      50 |     100 | 14-19             
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.744 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/66561050

Comment: Thanks, but i do not have { mocked } and without it mockReturnValueOnce does not work. What should I use instead? My ts-jest is 22.0.1 and jest is 25.1.0

Comment: @yovchokalev You can use type cast `const mUseRef  = useRef  as jest.Mock`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2021. Do not use enzyme!**

The whole story is explained thoroughly [here](https://www.piotrstaniow.pl/goodbye-enzyme).
Short story:

1. AirBNB(they created it) stopped supporting it and instead gave it to someone else and right now only one person is supporting it.
2. It has not been updated for 2 years, which means it does not support react 17(react 18 is right around the corner by the way). There are 3rd party adapters for react 17, but each of them has its issues and it faces the same problem of depending on a project, which has no guarantee of being supported.
3. Functional components(like the one in the question) are hard to make, because enzyme was not intended for them.
4. Enzyme uses some internal react features, which is discouraged and could create even worse problems if react changes.
5. Jest has moved a couple of version up, using different environment, which further complicates things.

The industry standard right now is [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library) It is also recommended  by the react team, who stopped using enzyme as well.